# G++ Compile Fail (Not Linking to header correctly)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, header, g++

I have code that compiles correctly in Visual Studios. I need to compile it using g++ but when I do I get a something like the text below. From what I understand this means it's not properly linking he header file that the undefined references are supposed to come from. The way I am linking them is also posted. Please suggest a fix?

```
extern "C" 
{
    #include "lexer.h"
}
```

"COMPILE_FAIL
Source.cpp: In function ‘void checkForAllRightEpsilon()’:
/tmp/ccQGWPkN.o: In function `parseFile()':
Source.cpp:(.text+0xe86): undefined reference to`getToken'
...
/tmp/ccQGWPkN.o:Source.cpp:(.text+0x1249): more undefined references to `token' follow"

Comment: Was `lexer.c` compiled using `gcc` (i.e. the c-compiler), not `g++` actually?

Comment: No, it was compiled using g++.

Comment: _"No, it was compiled using `g++`"_ Then this was probably wrong, use `gcc` to compile it as c-code. The marked duplicate has some explanations about c++ name mangling, and how linkage is affected by this.

Comment: The compiler automatically compiles as g++. The three files are main.cpp, lexer.c, and lexer.h. I believe it is compiling correctly in this respect?

Comment: _"The compiler automatically compiles as g++."_ What do you mean? How is it called? From an IDE or a makefile? You either remove the `extern "C"` block surrounding the `#include "lexer.h"` statement, or manage getting `lexer.c` compiled as plain c code.